# I ran apt-get dist-upgrade and my php stop working

Tags: php, debian, upgrade, apt-get, server-configuration

I have searched but couldn't find a resource that helped, so I have to say it out loud. Please help me. I mistakenly ran  `sudo apt-get upgrade -u dist-upgrade`
After that, all the websites on my server stopped working. I tried to check if Php is still installed by typing `php -v`but I got

`-bash: php: command not found`

I also tried to reinstall php using

`sudo apt-get install php`

And I saw this

```
sudo apt-get install php
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php : Depends: php7.2 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I tried running

```
Sudo apt-get install php7.2
```

And I saw this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.2 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.2 but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.2-fpm but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.2-cgi but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also tried installing the modules: and I get this:

```
root@matrixpluspluto:~# sudo apt-get install php7.2 php7.2-cli php7.2-c
gi php7.2-fpm libapache2-mod-php7.2 php7.2-opcache
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php7.2 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but 2.24-11+deb9u1 is to be installed
                         Depends: libsodium23 (>= 1.0.14) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.2-cgi : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but 2.24-11+deb9u1 is to be installed
              Depends: libsodium23 (>= 1.0.14) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.2-cli : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but 2.24-11+deb9u1 is to be installed
              Depends: libsodium23 (>= 1.0.14) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.2-fpm : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but 2.24-11+deb9u1 is to be installed
              Depends: libsodium23 (>= 1.0.14) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.2-opcache : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but 2.24-11+deb9u1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I checked and saw that libc6 v2.24 is already installed 
Please help me. Before this I was using php7.1 after the upgrade I started seeing 7.2. Anything I do concerning php doesn't work out. Pove been trying to fix this for more than 2 days, please help.

Comment: Can you `purge` / `remove` the existing `php` and reinstall. That should work

Comment: Try running `sudo apt install php7.2 php7.2-common php7.2-cli php7.2-fpm`
 and follow https://ayesh.me/Ubuntu-PHP-7.2 see if it helps

Comment: I tried removing.  `sudo apt-get purge php Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Package 'php' is not installed, so not removed'` that is what I got

Comment: @BlackMamba I tried it and it didn't work

Comment: Any new error ??

Comment: No new error. Gave the same error output on unmet dependencies. `Depends: libsodium23 (>=1.0.14) but it doesn't s not going to be installed`  `Depends: libc6 (>=.27) but 2.24-11+debu1 is to be installed` I tried installing libc6 but it's I already have the latest version `version 2.24-11+deb9u1`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you solved it yet but I had the same problem.

Solved it by running : 
**sudo apt-get purge php*** .

Note that this is not a good solution but a desperate one. Also I knew what php related packages I had installed, so I wasen't afraid of what the command would purge.
Then I watched what packages are being purged and **reintalled them**.
Everything working fine for now.